# Load content in div from a href tag in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to load all images before displaying them in a slideshow. I have been searching a lot but nothing seems to work. This is what i have so far and it doesn't work. I am loading images from the `<a>` tag from another div.

```
$('.slideshow').load(function(){
    if (loaded<length){
        first = $(settings.thumb).eq(loaded).find('a').attr("href");
        $('<img src="'+first1+'"/>').appendTo('.slideshow');
    }
    else{ $('.slideshow').show(); }
    loaded++;
});
```

Comment: Well we need more information. What is `loaded`? What is `length`? Maybe your HTML mark up. "It doesn't work" is often not well received on SO. Can you maybe read the console?

Comment: Maybe this could help you http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/ It is a library that helps you detect image loads.

Comment: i am trying to cache or load the images from the <a href> tag before i implement autoplay in the slideshow. I did it without the load function but every time a new image loads it placed me in the top of the page. After the images were played once than everything was good. That is why i thought if i load or cache the images first than this will not happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an event listener to each image to respond to when the browser has finished loading the image, then append it to your slideshow.

```
var $images = $("#div_containing_images img");
var numImages = $images.length;
var numLoaded = 0;
var $slideshow = $(".slideshow");

$images.each(function() {
  var $thisImg = $(this);
  $thisImg.on("load", function() {
    $thisImg.detach().appendTo($slideshow);
    numLoaded++;
    if (numLoaded == numImages) {
      $slideshow.show();
    }
  });
});
```

It's a good idea to also listen for the `error` event as well, in case the image fails to load.  That way you can increase `numLoaded` to account for broken image.  Otherwise, your slideshow will never be shown in the event the image is broken.

Also note, that by calling `detach()` followed by `appendTo()` I am am moving the image in the DOM.  If instead, you want to copy the image, use `clone()` instead of `detach()`.

*** EDIT TO MODIFY USER'S EXACT USE CASE ***

```
  var $images = $("li.one_photo a");
  var numImages = $images.length;
  var numLoaded = 0;

  $images.each(function() {
    $('<img />',
      { src: $(this).attr("href") })
      .appendTo('.slideshow')
      .on("load error", function() {
        numLoaded++;
        if(numLoaded == numImages) {
          $('.slideshow').show();
        }
      });
  });
```

*** EDIT #2 ***

Just realized you were putting everything in the `$(".slideshow").load()` function.  Since `$(".slideshow")` represents a DIV, it will never raise a `load` event, and the corresponding function will never execute.  Edited above accordingly.

Comment: Thnx :-)..just one more question the images should be loaded from the <a href> in the <li> tag. How can i load the link from that?

Comment: You could do exactly what you've done above to create a new image element appended to the slideshow.  But instead of immediately incremented `loaded`, you would still need to add the event listener to each image you append.  Then increment loaded when the `load` or `error` event fires.

Comment: I added to my answer to show how you might accomplish exactly what you are trying to do.